# Need to format complex foreach and IF statements to better formatted LINQ expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, foreach, linq-to-sql

I have a Foreach Statement as shown below

```
foreach (var fieldMappingOption in collectionHelper.FieldMappingOptions
    .Where(fmo => fmo.IsRequired && !fmo.IsCalculated 
     && !fmo.FieldDefinition.Equals( MMPConstants.FieldDefinitions.FieldValue) 
     && (implicitParents || anyParentMappings 
         || fmo.ContainerType == collectionHelper.SelectedOption.ContainerType))) 
{
    if (!collectionHelper.FieldMappingHelpers
            .Any(fmh => fmh.SelectedOption.Equals(fieldMappingOption))) 
    {
        requiredMissing = true;
        var message = String.Format(
           "The MMP column {0} is required and therefore must be mapped to a {1} column.", 
           fieldMappingOption.Label, session.ImportSource.CollectionLabel);
        session.ErrorMessages.Add(message);
    }
}
```

Can I break the above complex foreach and IF statements into better formatted LINQ expression. Also, performance wise which will be better. Please suggest.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking here. Nothing seems very complex in your code. What do you mean by "better formatted LINQ expression"? You can improve performance by changing the `String.Format` to simple string concatenation. `String.Format` is slower than string concatenation.

Comment: This might be a better candidate for codereview.stackexchange.

Comment: Thanks, @ZoharPeled for the comment.
I wanted to know that Is there any possiblity where we can change the Foreach to a Linq statement as the conditions are too long

Answer (score 1):

**Re : Change the Foreach to a Linq statement**

Well, you could convert the two for loops into a LINQ Select, and since inside the loop, you've only one branch with an additional predicate, you could combine the predicate into the outer loop, something like so:

```
var missingFieldMappingOptions = collectionHelper.FieldMappingOptions
  .Where(fmo => fmo.IsRequired && !fmo.IsCalculated 
     && !fmo.FieldDefinition.Equals( MMPConstants.FieldDefinitions.FieldValue) 
     && (implicitParents || anyParentMappings 
         || fmo.ContainerType == collectionHelper.SelectedOption.ContainerType))
     && !collectionHelper.FieldMappingHelpers
        .Any(fmh => fmh.SelectedOption.Equals(fmo)))
  .Select(fmo => 
      $"The MMP column {fmo.Label} is required and therefore" +
      $" must be mapped to a {session.ImportSource.CollectionLabel} column."); 

var requiredMissing = missingFieldMappingOptions.Any();
session.ErrorMessages.AddRange(missingFieldMappingOptions)
```

However, even LINQ can't make the filter clauses in the `.Where` disappear, so the LINQ Select is hardly more readable than the for loop, and isn't really any more performant either (there may be some marginal benefit to setting the `requiredMissing` flag and adding to `session.ErrorMessages` in one bulk chunk.

**Performance**

From a performance perspective, the below is problematic as it will be `O(N log N)` when combined in the outer for loop (fortunately `.Any()` will return early if a match is found, otherwise it would be as bad as N^2):

```
if (!collectionHelper
    .FieldMappingHelpers.Any(fmh => fmh.SelectedOption.Equals(fieldMappingOption)))
```

Does `FieldMappingOption` have a unique key? If so, then suggest add a `Dictionary<Key, FieldMappingOption>` to `collectionHelper` and then use `.ContainsKey(key)` which [approaches O(1)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), e.g.

```
!collectionHelper
    .SelectedFieldMappingOptions.ContainsKey(fieldMappingOption.SomeKey)
```

Even if there isn't a unique key, you could use a decent `HashCode` on `FieldMappingOption` and key by that to get a similar effect, although you'll need to consider what happens in the event of a hash collision.

**Readability**

The `Where` predicate in the outer for loop is arguably messy and could use some refactoring (for readability, if not for performance).

IMO most of the where clauses could be moved into `FieldMappingOption` as a meta property, e.g. wrap up

```
fmo.IsRequired 
&& !fmo.IsCalculated 
&& !fmo.FieldDefinition.Equals(MMPConstants.FieldDefinitions.FieldValue)
```

into a property, e.g. `fmo.MustBeValidated` etc.

You could squeeze minor performance by ensuring the predicate returns false as soon as possible, by rearranging the && clauses which are most likely to fail first, but wouldn't do so if it impacts the flow of readability of the code.

Comment: IMHO the `fmo.MustBeValidated` suggestion is the best thing about this post. +1 for that. However, unless there's a real, measured performance problem, then that's premature optimization.